# On mouseover, use jquery round plugin to a table row

Tags: jquery, css, rounded-corners

I have a table row which on hover has background color. Right now, the row background is a squared one. I want to make the corners rounded using JQuery corner plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

```
table tbody tr#ClickableRow:hover
    {
        background-color: #fbf6e7;
        cursor:pointer; }
```

On hover, the row will get background color from CSS and should get rounded corners effect from JQuery Corner Plugin. Is this possible?

```
$('#ElemenetsToBeRounded').each(function() { 
    var q = $(this).corner("rounded 8px"); 
     eval(q); 
});
```

This rounds the corners.

```
<tr id="ClickableRow">
    <td>
<a href="http://somesite.com">Go Here</a>
<p> To find about all the interestng animals found in this tourist attractions including 
zebra, giraffe etc
</p>
    </td>

<td>Call us at 444-444-2322 to register</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try changing #ElemenetsToBeRounded to #ClickableRow - you might have to round the `td` tags...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do it through css as now most of the modern browsers support border radius. For old browsers which do not support there are hacks available which are easy to implement. Take a look at this http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are only going to use

```
.corner("rounded 8px")
```

I would just add in the hover of the css the border-radius code.

```
table tbody tr#ClickableRow:hover
{
    background-color: #fbf6e7;
    cursor:pointer; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
```